# Update json column value in eloquent model in laravel - Database-Oracle

Tags: laravel, oracle, eloquent

In my project `current_profile` is a JSON object column for `EmployeePromotionAndShifting` model. I want to update a key named `division_i` of `current_profile` column.
The JSON object is like this:

```
"current_profile" =>
{"staff_id":"2927","division_id":"84","department_id":"200","unit_id":null}
```

I am getting an error:

> "This database engine does not support JSON operations." at
> vendor\yajra\laravel-oci8\src\Oci8\Query\Grammars\OracleGrammar.php:1

Code to update in database!

```
EmployeePromotionAndShifting::where('staff_id',$currentProfile['staff_id'])->update(['current_profile->division_id' => 555,]);
```

I want to update `division_id` key of `current_profile` column for a particular row.

Comment: Fetch your json as a variable and edit the `division_id` value then update the column value or use a database that supports json operations.

Comment: can you share a demo please.@A.Seddighi